# If the selected option is greater than others, disable other options

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have two Selectbox groups.
When the user selects an item from the 1st Selectbox group; According to the selected Value, I want to disable some of the items in the 2nd Selectbox group.

Below is my sample code. The example scenario I want to do based on the following set of code is as follows:

```
<select name="group1" id="group1">
  <option value="12">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="13">Opt 2</option>
  <option value="21">Opt 3</option>
  <option value="22">Opt 4</option>
  <option value="24">Opt 5</option>
  <option value="35">Opt 6</option>
  <option value="57">Opt 7</option>
  <option value="62">Opt 8</option>
</select>

<select name="group2" id="group2">
  <option value="12">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="13">Opt 2</option>
  <option value="21">Opt 3</option>
  <option value="22">Opt 4</option>
  <option value="24">Opt 5</option>
  <option value="35">Opt 6</option>
  <option value="57">Opt 7</option>
  <option value="62">Opt 8</option>
</select>
```

For example: If the user selects `<option value="22">Opt 4</option>` from the 1st Selectbox,

In Selectbox 2. group this option items should automatically become "disabled" in the group:

```
<option value="12">Opt 1</option>
<option value="13">Opt 2</option>
<option value="21">Opt 3</option>
<option value="22">Opt 4</option>
```

So what I want to do is as follows: According to the value values in the Selectbox, after each item selection, it should be able to select larger values of the current selection in the other Selectbox step.

Comment: So what have you tried? We know what you need but you get more help when you show your attempts to solve your own issue

Comment: Show your best guess at how this would work, even if it's just describing the sequence step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Using the jQuery `on('change'` listener, we can access the current selected value with `$(this).val()` - then loop through the second select, setting `.prop('disabled'` to true/false based on it's value being equal to or less than the first selected value. Because we're comparing `Numbers` but the values we're getting are `strings`, we need to convert them with `Number()`, `parseInt()` or the shorthand prefix operator `+`

```js
$('#group1').on('change', function() {
  let val = Number($(this).val());
  $('#group2 option').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', Number($(this).val()) <= val)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="group1" id="group1">
  <option value="12">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="13">Opt 2</option>
  <option value="21">Opt 3</option>
  <option value="22">Opt 4</option>
  <option value="24">Opt 5</option>
  <option value="35">Opt 6</option>
  <option value="57">Opt 7</option>
  <option value="62">Opt 8</option>
</select>

<select name="group2" id="group2">
  <option value="12">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="13">Opt 2</option>
  <option value="21">Opt 3</option>
  <option value="22">Opt 4</option>
  <option value="24">Opt 5</option>
  <option value="35">Opt 6</option>
  <option value="57">Opt 7</option>
  <option value="62">Opt 8</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @ozan - did this solve your question? Did the other answer? If either did, please choose one and mark as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#group1').on('change' , function(){
  
  var value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  
  $('#group2').find('option').prop('disabled',false);
  
  $('#group2').find('option').each(function(i,e){
  
    var opt = $(e);
    
    if(opt.val() < value){
      opt.prop('disabled',true);
    }
  })

  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="group1" id="group1">
  <option value="12">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="13">Opt 2</option>
  <option value="21">Opt 3</option>
  <option value="22">Opt 4</option>
  <option value="24">Opt 5</option>
  <option value="35">Opt 6</option>
  <option value="57">Opt 7</option>
  <option value="62">Opt 8</option>
</select>

<hr>

<select name="group2" id="group2">
  <option value="12">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="13">Opt 2</option>
  <option value="21">Opt 3</option>
  <option value="22">Opt 4</option>
  <option value="24">Opt 5</option>
  <option value="35">Opt 6</option>
  <option value="57">Opt 7</option>
  <option value="62">Opt 8</option>
</select>
```

I am sharing an example above. When there is a change in the first selectbox, it takes the selected value and compares the second selectbox, if the selected value is large, it adds a disabled attribute.

Comment: Boolean attributes should be set with `prop` rather than `attr`. See [`.prop()` vs `.attr()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/215552).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes prop can be used instead of attr :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying it *can* be used. I'm saying it *should* be used. In other words, your code *might* work with `attr`/`removeAttr`, but it *will* work with `prop`.